# How can I make a React app using React-router redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I am new to React and have followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bananaoomarang/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.9zkjbp8nz) to make an app. I have got login working via a user token stored in a cookie, and now I need to make sure only authorised users can access the content.

What is the correct way (using React-router/Redux) to get the redirect to happen so that if a user goes straight to http://app.com/content, they will be bounced to the login page?

Comment: There is a great example for authentication in React+Redux, take a look at it: [joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example](https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to set up an `onEnter` hook for the relevant authenticated routes that checks that the user is authenticated, then redirects the user to a `/login` or other route if not.

It's ideal to handle auth checking this way, because it integrates nicely with server rendering in isomorphic apps in such a way as to make it straightforward to generate a 302 when running on a server.

The specifics will depend on how exactly you track authentication information, but the React Router "Auth Flow" example gives a good generic overview: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow.